# Laravel8 npm run dev outputs: ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: laravel, npm

#### Goal

Avoid error message.
I have been getting the following error message when I run the command `npm run dev`:

```
npm notice 
npm notice New major version of npm available! 7.6.1 -> 8.1.4
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.1.4
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.1.4 to update!
npm notice 

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Found: acorn@7.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/acorn
npm ERR!   acorn@"^7.0.0" from acorn-node@1.8.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/acorn-node
npm ERR!     acorn-node@"^1.6.1" from detective@5.2.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/detective
npm ERR!       detective@"^5.2.0" from tailwindcss@2.2.19
npm ERR!       node_modules/tailwindcss
npm ERR!         dev tailwindcss@"^2.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional acorn@"^8.5.0" from terser@5.10.0
npm ERR! node_modules/terser
npm ERR!   terser@"^5.9.0" from laravel-mix@6.0.39
npm ERR!   node_modules/laravel-mix
npm ERR!     dev laravel-mix@"^6.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!   terser@"^5.7.2" from terser-webpack-plugin@5.2.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin
npm ERR!     terser-webpack-plugin@"^5.2.4" from laravel-mix@6.0.39
npm ERR!     node_modules/laravel-mix
npm ERR!       dev laravel-mix@"^6.0.6" from the root project
npm ERR!     1 more (webpack)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/ml/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ml/.npm/_logs/2021-12-02T07_41_55_149Z-debug.log
```

#### Quick Solution:

I can avoid the problem / error message with the following command:
`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`.

**Output:**

```js
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

added 807 packages, and audited 808 packages in 12s

84 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

#### Question

What do I have to do to run `npm install` again without getting the error message?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue too. I have fixed it using this line

npm i acorn --dev

then run again

npm install && install run dev

Answer (score 0):

npm install npm@latest -g

then

npm install webpack-dev-server --save-dev

working for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel Homestead Package for any Vagrant Environment, then don't run the command inside the Vagrant Project Directory.
Go outside to the local directory of the project and run these commands.
[image of commands inside vagrant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBob4.png)

You should run these here::
[image of commands outside vagrant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUbOT.png)